# SQLite julianday() and Android

Tags: android, sqlite

SQLite has nice function - julianday. It sems to be easy way to store date, compare, sort... (if I'm mistaken - why?)
But I can't find any way to manipulate dates like julianday in Android APIs. 
Is there any way (except make my own or use third-party libraries) to convert julianday to Date and back?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compute?

Comment: e.g. julianday(CURRENT_DATE)  = 2457812.5. How to convert it into Date() in java?

Answer (score 1):

The only feature of SQLite's `julianday()` which seems very useful is its ability to find the difference in days between two date strings.  This is possible because the number of days since the start of the Julian calendar can be found for two dates, and their difference computed.  Knowing the number of days which has elapsed since November 24, 4714 B.C. by itself is much less useful, unless you were alive at that time, in which case you might be a vampire.

We can also find the difference in days between two dates in Java Android, though it is a bit more cumbersome:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
try {
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2017-02-21");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("2017-02-28");

    long diffInMillis = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    int numDays = (int)diffInMillis / 1000*60*60*24;

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java uses milliseconds timestamps, which are the same as Unix timestamps, but with milliseconds instead of seconds.

So to convert a julian day number into a Java milliseconds value, use `strftime()` and go through a Unix timestamp:

```
SELECT strftime('%s', TimestampColumn) * 1000 FROM ...
```

To convert a Java milliseconds value into a julian day number, don't insert it directly, but call `julianday()` on it:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (..., julianday(? / 1000, 'unixepoch'), ...);
```